# How to sms sql agent job status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, email, ssis, sms

There are scheduled sql agent jobs runnig on sql server 2014.We would like to get the
sms once the job finished {Need to know the job status ,success/failure }.How to implement this? The steps consists of SSIS and T-SQL

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the built-in options on the Notifications page of the a job's properties in SSMS.
The email option could be used via a SMS gateway, and is configure as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186358(v=sql.120).aspx